# Diffeomorphism induced by small perturbation

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gt.geometric-topology, riemann-surfaces, algebraic-surfaces, surfaces

Consider the surface $S_{\epsilon}$ defined as:
\begin{align}
%S&=\{\vec x \in \mathbf{R}^3: x=0\}, \\
S_{\epsilon}&=\{\vec x \in \mathbf{R}^3:\epsilon (x^2 + y^2 + z^2 - 1) + x=0\}.
\end{align}
Obviously $S_0=\mathbf R^2$. For $\epsilon$ small, we expect that each point, $\vec x$, on $\mathbf R^2$ undergoes a small change $\vec x\to\vec x +\vec \delta$ to lie on $S_\epsilon$. In fact $\vec \delta$ can be expanded in a series in $\epsilon$. Further, it can be arranged for $\vec \delta$ to lie completely perpendicular to $\mathbf R^2$ (i.e. $\vec \delta$ lies in the $\hat x$ direction). However that is odds with the fact that for $y=z=0$ (for example), there are two solutions for $x$ lying on $S_\epsilon$. How can one explain this?

Comment: What about the simpler question where you consider the equation $\epsilon x^2 + x = 0$?  The heuristic you explained is reasonable,  but it is simply not true in general.

Comment: @PhilTosteson It probably has to do with the fact that the series in $\epsilon$ doesn't converge sometimes?